# Firebase gcm messages not receiving because of background limitation oreo while app remove recent tray

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I am facing this issue `Firebase gcm` messages not receiving because of background limitation Oreo and pie updates how to solve this issue

Its not working but some other apps like Truecaller and WhatsApp and all working right now.

Comment: newly updated android version oreo and pie have a new feature to battery optimization have to stop the application to receive notification after removing the application from the recent tray. and one more thing Truecaller and WhatsApp are whitelisted from google so they don't need to battery optimization.

Comment: https://medium.com/globallogic-latinoamerica-mobile/firebase-cloud-messaging-warning-updating-to-android-oreo-1343fe894bd5

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Messaging Service shouldn't be affected by the limitations of `Oreo` or `Pie`. And as per your question tag, it seems you are using broadcast receiver to receive those notifications/data messages. So you should use `FirebaseMessagingService` to receive the cloud message and handle it properly there. You don't need broadcast receiver for it.